# Haskell - have a function return an empty character

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to create a function that drops every n'th element from a string.

```
dropEvery :: String -> Int -> String
dropEvery str n = map (\(char, indx) -> if indx `mod` n /= 0 then char else ' ') (zip str [1..])
```

Right now it simply replaces every n'th element with a space, but what am I supposed to put after the "else" if I want it to return an "empty char". I understand that such a thing doesn't exist in Haskell so the question is - how am I supposed to tell Haskell to not return anything and just move on to the next char?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this with just `map`, by definition it can't change the length of the collection it's applied to.  However, you can get this to work without too many changes by switching to `concatMap`.  This function requires the your function that you're mapping return a list, then it concatenates all the results together.  All you'd need to do is

```
dropEvery str n =
    concatMap (\(char, indx) -> if indx `mod` n /= 0 then [char] else []) (zip str [1..])
```

Comment: I did attempt to put "[]" after "else", but of course ended up getting type errors. concatMap is a good idea.

Comment: @RaulŠpilev The problem comes from assuming that there is something called an "empty `Char`".  This would be like an "empty `Int`" or an "empty `Bool`", you can have an `Int` that is 0, but not one that doesn't have a value at all (not counting `undefined`).  In order to have emptiness, you need a container.  Strings are containers, since they're simply a list of `Char`s, so by having a function `(Char, Int) -> [Char]`, you can use `concatMap` over a `[(Char, Int)] to get out a `[Char]`.

Answer (score 5):

`map` preserves the structure of the list, while your operations modifies it by removing elements. This means you can't use `map`, but you can use `mapMaybe` which allows you to provide a function which returns `Nothing` for elements you want to remove from the output:

```
import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)
dropEvery str n = mapMaybe (\(char, indx) -> if indx `mod` n /= 0 then Just(char) else Nothing) (zip str [1..])
```

Comment: I'd have to run some tests to be sure but this might be a more efficient solution than mine

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. I was thinking about using "Nothing" and "Just (char)", but wasn't sure how without getting "Couldn't match expected type" errors."mapMaybe" solves this. Also, now I understand how the map function works much better.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without `mod`. I'm going to flip the order of the arguments to make this more idiomatic.

```
dropEvery :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
dropEvery n xs = map fst . filter ((/= n) . snd) $ zip xs (cycle [1..n])
```

If speed is critical, it would likely be most efficient to use this technique with explicit recursion or `foldr`. Something like this:

```
dropEvery n xs = foldr go (`seq` []) xs n where
  go _ r 1 = r n
  go x r k = x : r (k - 1)
```