# Haskell : Syntax error

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am use Haskell stack.

```
module Len () where

   my_nthele :: String -> Integer -> Char
   my_nthele [] n = ''
   my_nthele (x:xs) n  | n == 0 = x
                       | otherwise = my_nthele xs (n-1)
```

Haskell interpreter shows "src/Len.hs:5:1: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)"

I have no clue about what is wrong.

Comment: `''` is not a valid character.

Comment: @user2407038, ah, i see, then how to return a empty char in haskell?

Comment: @anru https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554499/haskell-have-a-function-return-an-empty-character

Comment: ok, see that, I should use Maybe

Comment: See also [`at*`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-0.3.15/docs/Safe.html#v:atMay) from the safe package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [syntax for character literals dictates that you need something between the single quotes](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-200002.6):

> ### 2.6 Character and String Literals
>
> ```
> char  →   '(graphic|space|escape⟨\&⟩)' [remark: heavily simplified]
> ```
>
> Character literals are written between single quotes, as in 'a'

Therefore, `''` isn't valid syntax for a character. How should it be? There's no character to begin with. The type `Char` does not contain the notion of not being a character, just as `Int` does not contain the notion of not existing.

That's exactly what `Maybe` is for:

```
my_nthele :: String -> Integer -> Maybe Char
my_nthele [] n = Nothing
my_nthele (x:xs) n  | n == 0 = Just x
                    | otherwise = my_nthele xs (n-1)
```

By the way, as an exercise, try to make your function more generic, so that one can also use `my_nthele [1..10] 3 == Just 4`. It's not hard, but let's you play around with `Maybe`.

Comment: thanks mate. i was just playing around String/Char Type. but '' is not a character really confused me. I do not know about language design theory, but like programmer always count from 0 not 1. '' is a character for me just seems natural.

Comment: A `Char` in Haskell cannot be "empty". You can set it to `'\NUL'`, but that's something else. It's the same as in C, you cannot set `char x = ''` there. In your other languages, PHP and JS, there is only a minor distinction between a single character and a string, thus `''` is an empty ___string___ in those languages.